# Use Lebesque-Index (Z-Order) for 2D Coordinates and include velocity in a clever way for collision detection

Tags: algorithm, collision-detection, z-order

**Question & Background information:**

The [Lebesgue curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order_curve) seems to be a nice way to determine collision of objects near to each other. I am currently trying to detect possible 2D-collisions where i also have to consider the speed of these objects.

**e.g.:** the collision might be *between* two up following frames (**frame1** and **frame2**) and therefore has  to be predicted at **frame1**.

Because the velocity of the objects can be very high, even object far far away from each other might collide before **frame2**.

**So is there a clever way to use Z-Ordering over 2D and include the velocity?**

My first thinking is, that velocity could be represented as the third dimension, but as it will be ordered, there will be objects far up or down my Lebesque-Index.

Every paper or ideas are very welcome!

Comment: @Kirk Beard, thanks for editing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After tinkering around i found this solution by myself:

1. By maintaining the objects it is easy to find the currently fastest moving one (linear time).
2. To check for collision using Lebesque-Index, calculate the maximum possible distance using the objects velocity and the one with the currently highest velocity.
3. Use Lebesque-Index down and up the depth of the max(x,y) position.

In worst-case it's still O(n^2).